# Change dataGridView Cell Formatting on button click (not on cell click)

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I am coding Hotel Booking Manager for school project. I need to chceck if the guest in hotel has checked in or chcecked out. If guest is not chcecked in or chcecked out the day that is writen in database, I need to change color of row, to mark that this reservation needs atention.

I am trying to find solution to change cell formatting on button click(for now, later it will be scheduled task). I know how to change cell formatting while it is loading data to dataGridView.

I have been trying with this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[(int)myReader["id"]].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
```

But it says that there is no Style method, which I understand because it is method from CellFormatting Class.

I could write code in CellFormatting class, but I can't call it on button click  because I don't know what to write between () for sender and e.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Best to be careful based on the sorting that the database ID from `myReader["id"]` may not be the same as the row index in `dataGridView1`

Comment: Instead of `(int)myReader["id"]` you should use a loop on `DataGridView.Rows` collection.

Comment: A moments ago I realised that when I got Out of range exception for 10th time. Already once made this mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DefaultCellStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a [`DataGridViewRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow(v=vs.110).aspx) to set some style for the row, for example:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    //if some criteria
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Also you can change the style in some suitable event, for example you can hanlde [`RowPrePaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint(v=vs.110).aspx) and check some criteria on the row and change its style:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    //you can find the row this way: this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
    //then check some criteria on some cell values
    //then you can set the style for row this way:
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```